# Export Location Using Access Macro

Tags: ms-access, macros

I have an interesting question. I have an access database and there is a macro that exports certain queries to excel. That is working fine. However, this database is saved on a shared folder of a local network. If I wanted the macro to export the database to the documents folder or desktop folder of the user, how would I do this?

Also, kind of a side note - is it possible to attach some sort of vba code to open the exported document in excel as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the environ function to get this kind of information. For example the users desktop can be found by calling this bit of code

Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop"

For opening the file after you could use this bit of code that opens up a file using the default application for that extension

Application.FollowHyperlink “C:\Your_excel_sheet.xls”

That should set you in the right direction

Comment: Where do I place the Environ code at? Can I enter that into the design view of the macro or does that need posted in vba somewhere?

Comment: Also, since the location will change depending on who saved the excel doc, how can I give them a hyperlink to follow?

Comment: Application.FollowHyperlink works with all file names, not just the implied web protocols (e.g., "c:\Documents and Settings\Username\Filename.ext", not just "http://MyWebsite.com/Folder/").